# Print `numpy.ndarray` on a single line

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, formatting

While using scipy/numpy, I do get information that I store into a  `numpy.ndarray`

```
>>> a
array([[ 0.15555605,  0.51031528,  0.84580176,  0.06722675],
       [ 0.60556045,  0.62721023, -0.48979983, -0.04152777],
       [-0.78044785,  0.58837543, -0.21146041, -0.13568023],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
>>> print(a)
[[ 0.15555605  0.51031528  0.84580176  0.06722675]
 [ 0.60556045  0.62721023 -0.48979983 -0.04152777]
 [-0.78044785  0.58837543 -0.21146041 -0.13568023]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          1.        ]]
```

How can I print the result on a single line?

I already checked:

```
>>> numpy.get_printoptions()
{'precision': 8, 'threshold': 1000, 'edgeitems': 3, 'linewidth': 75, 'suppress': False, 'nanstr': 'nan', 'infstr': 'inf', 'formatter': None}
```

But even setting `linewidth` to 1000 does no change this. Is there a way to change the displayed format of that type?

Is it also possible to add comma in between each number (like the array display but without the surrounding `array(...)`)?

Comment: If you want the array "as-is" printed in one line, you can try `print(a.tolist())`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to print a `numpy.array` into a single line, you can convert it to a list with its built-in function `numpy.tolist()`

Example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)))
```

Simple print of array:

```
print(arr)
[[1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

In comparison with `numpy.tolist()`:

```
print(array.tolist())
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: `list(arr)` does the job more concise.

Comment: `array.tolist()` and `list(arr)` are not the same. `print(list(arr))` gives `[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]`

Answer (score 8):

NumPy provides a few ways to customize the printing, for example [`np.array2string`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html).

For this answer I assume you have such an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
... arr = np.array([[ 0.15555605,  0.51031528,  0.84580176,  0.06722675],
...                 [ 0.60556045,  0.62721023, -0.48979983, -0.04152777],
...                 [-0.78044785,  0.58837543, -0.21146041, -0.13568023],
...                 [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

- If you want to display all items you need to make sure that you set `threshold` to `np.inf`.
- In case you want to have `,` as separator, you can set `separator` to `','`.

However it doesn't have an option to remove the line breaks, just

- `max_line_width` which gives the number of characters printed in one line for the innermost dimension. So it works for 1D arrays when you set `max_line_width=np.inf` but it doesn't work out of the box for ND arrays.

Fortunately it returns a string that can be manipulated, for example by removing all linebreaks:

```
>>> np.array2string(arr, threshold=np.inf, max_line_width=np.inf, separator=',').replace('\n', '')
'[[ 0.15555605, 0.51031528, 0.84580176, 0.06722675], [ 0.60556045, 0.62721023,-0.48979983,-0.04152777], [-0.78044785, 0.58837543,-0.21146041,-0.13568023], [ 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ]]'
```

Or use a regular expression to remove all whitespaces:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', '', np.array2string(arr, threshold=np.inf, max_line_width=np.inf, separator=','))
'[[0.15555605,0.51031528,0.84580176,0.06722675],[0.60556045,0.62721023,-0.48979983,-0.04152777],[-0.78044785,0.58837543,-0.21146041,-0.13568023],[0.,0.,0.,1.]]'
```

Agreed these aren't really "short" and they are also slower than converting to a `list` with `.tolist()` and then to a string but it's probably a good alternative especially if you want to customize the printed result without creating a (potentially huge) unnecessary list.

Comment: To add to this, If you have a list object and want to do the same, just wrap it in `np.array()`