# Write long list to file all on one line

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, printing

In Python the following code:

```
data = [np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),[7]]
with open('A:\\examplefile.txt', 'w', newline='') as file:
      file.write(str([item for item in data]))
```

writes the nested list to multiple lines in the file, thus:

```
[array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]]), [7]]
```

How might I write the entire list onto on line in the file? e.g.:

```
[array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),[7]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy formats ndarray output by using '\n' and whitespaces such that it is readable in form of a matrix. So replacing '\n' and whitespace will do the trick.

Try this,

```
data = [np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),[7]]
with open('A:\\examplefile.txt', 'w', newline='') as file:
    file.write(str(data).replace('\n','').replace(' ',''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for but numpys default way of printing/writing arrays is a newline per item. One of the ways you can circumvent this is by checking if the item in the list is a numpy array and converting it to a list like so.

```
import numpy as np
data = [np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),[7]]
with open('examplefile.txt', 'w') as file:
    a = []
    for item in data:
        if type(item) == np.ndarray:
            item = item.tolist()
        a.append(item)
    file.write(str(a))
```

[Here is another alternative if you want to change numpy's default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49438934/6855168)