# Reshape DataFrame to np.array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Good afternoon,
I have a dataframe with the dimension (963,1), how can I change something like this for a numpy format:

```
array ([244.1462534,212.68483386, 212.04058487, 236.39615555]
```

when I use, np.array (a), it appears to me, each element in a different row

```
[244.1462534,
244.1462534,
244.1462534,
244.1462534]
```

as there are many it is difficult to see it like this

Comment: can you try a.shape ?

Comment: Your result is already a 1D array

Comment: Maybe you can print it in a single line with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44140147/9346979

Comment: `values` from a full `dataframe` is 2d, e.g (963,1).  But one column is a `Series` which is 1d.  So you can either reshape the array, or select the column first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a 1 column frame:

```
In [590]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(5), columns=['x'])                                             
In [591]: df                                                                                         
Out[591]: 
   x
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

The array from that is (5,1) shaped:

```
In [592]: df.values                                                                                  
Out[592]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

One column is a Series, which is 1d:

```
In [594]: df['x']                                                                                    
Out[594]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: x, dtype: int64
In [595]: df['x'].values                                                                             
Out[595]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

But if you have the (5,1) shape array, there are lots of ways of reshaping it:

```
In [596]: df.values.ravel()                                                                          
Out[596]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

`ravel`, `flatten`, `reshape`, `squeeze`, even indexing.  All these can be found in the basic `numpy` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `values` to convert dataframe to Numpy array. Check the [Docs.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

```
df.values
```

You can reshape if you want a flattened np array

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10))
print (df.shape)
print (df.values.reshape(-1))
```

Output:

```
(10, 1)
[-1.43902815  0.72724325 -0.36741276 -1.96696158  0.5852711  -2.03214297
  0.11657485 -1.77276773  0.33315229 -1.37454383]
```